# 7" tablet display simulator for web development

Tags: web, tablet

I'd like to know if such a thing exists, and where to get it if it does, I guess it should exist but I cannot find it. I'm developing the design of a web page and I want to know how it looks on a 7" tablet, but if I want to test it, I've either to pass the pages to the tablet, or at best, display it on a android emulator, but this slows down the development notoriously, what I would be looking for would be an application or a browser plugin that if activated would directly display it on my PC screen the same way it would do in a 7" inch tablet.

Answer (score 0):

Don't be fixed on the 7", tablets with the same physical size can have different resolutions. The resolution determines how the page is rendered, so the only thing you really need is to resize your browser window to the specific resolution. There are various extensions for all browsers where you can define sizes and change your browser size with a mouseclick.